# Incorrect proof- why?

Tags: proof-explanation, fake-proofs

I know that this proof for $1+1≠0$ is incorrect- can someone explain where the logic is incorrect?

Proof by contradiction:

Assume $1+1=0.$ Then:

$$2=0$$ $$2\cdot\frac12=0\cdot\frac12$$ $$1=0$$ ...which is a contradiction.

Comment: By writing down $1/2$, you are implicitly assuming that $2$ is invertible, I.e., not zero.

Comment: It's shaky because you are using tools from a higher level of maths (division / fractions) to prove a very low level result (integer uniqueness).

Comment: Ah,  but why is this a contradiciton

Comment: @MichaelBurr Using field axioms, doesn't the existence of multiplicative inverses let me make this move?

Comment: @ChrisDugale I was thinking that this is the incorrect step as well, but there's an axiom that states 0≠1, no?

Comment: There is, but note that in the finite field $\mathbb F_2$, $1 + 1 = 0$.

Comment: There are only multiplicative inverses for nonzero elements, however.  By assuming a multiplicative inverse exists, you are concurrently assuming that $2$ is not zero.

Comment: @eyeballfrog so 0≠1 doesn't apply, so I cannot assume that 1=0 is a contradiction. That makes sense! Is the step to assume that 2 is invertible and not zero also incorrect as others have said?

Comment: The field axioms alone cannot prove $1 + 1 \ne 0$ because there is a field where that is false: $\mathbb F_2$. If you want to show this is true of the reals, you'll need to use something more than that.

Comment: You can prove that $1 \ne 0$ with work.  However if $1+1 = 2 = 0$ then you can not assume the number called $1/2$ actually exist.  As pointed out, in $\mathbb F_2$ $ 2 *does* equal $0$.but there is no such number as $1/2$ at all.

Answer (score 0):

The question could probably use some clarification.
You are making two assumptions.

The first, explicit, that $1+1$ equals $0$ (which is correct e.g. in $\mathbb{F}_2$).

The second, implicit, that $1+1=2$ has a multiplicative inverse (by writing it as $1/2$).

The two assumptions together indeed imply that $1=0$, which is no contradiction: it just means you are in the [Zero Ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_ring).